# How to remove hijacked website in chromium

Tags: chromium

I think my chromium browser has been hijacked. From now and then, when i surf to a website it automatically changes to hXXp://lp.zpdownload.info/mv/ with some advertisement for movies and to download a file. The only think i can do is to type in the website adress again and then it directs me correctly. 
How can i remove this? I'm working on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Was a Chrome extension ever added?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try purging Google Chrome. This will remove your history, favorites, and everything that isn't cloud-synched.

Open up Synaptic Package Manager. If you don't have it, install it from the Ubuntu Software Center as it is quite useful.

In Synaptic, search for `Chrome` or `Chromium` in the quick search bar. If you see any with green filled in boxes, that means they are installed. Click on the green box and select the option to remove completely with configuration. Now, click the checkmark in the top bar of the Synaptic window to apply changes. Confirm as needed.

Then, reinstall Google Chrome or Chromium. You can do so within Synaptic by searching `chromium-browser` and clicking the box in its row in the list of packages to install it, then clicking the checkmark to perform the planned installation.

Thanks to Vasa1, I've realized this may not help.

So, type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `nautilus  ~/.config/`. Now, rename the `chromium` folder to `oldchromium` if it exists, and do something similar with the `google-chrome` folder.

With that said, if you *did* cloudsync, any other Chrome installations also cloudsynched may be hijacked in the same way.